# Proper method of installing man pages

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm working on a software package within my org for deployment.  Unlike other packages, this now includes *man pages*.  Per our team's standards, I'd like to install them to `/opt/teamsw/doc/man{1,5}`.  I'd like to perform this in the proper way in order to update the manual page system's database, etc.  How is this done properly?

I've done some research and have found [this link at Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html/Packaging_Guide/sect-Software_Collection_manpath_Support.html).  However, that link makes no mention of using `mandb` to update the `/etc/man_db.conf`.  Is that not necessary?  It certainly doesn't seem to be if I install to more "standard" locations such as `/usr/share/man/man{1,2,...}`.  However, this means breaking from our Team's policy on where we install "our stuff."  In addition, how would this file be used during package installation?  From what I can tell, it's only used when a new shell is started.  This wouldn't be the case during installation of the package.  Thus, the additional directories would be absent and having `mandb` update the database would be useless.  Unless, I do not fully understand the process.

One question that I do have, regarding the instructions at the link provided, is there an advantage to specifying the script to update the `MANPATH` env var as a source to the package?  Briefly,

```
# manpage.sh - brief script to add extra paths to MANPATH
export MANPATH=${MANPATH}:/opt/teamsw/doc/man1:/opt/teamsw/doc/man5

# abbreviated spec file for package
SOURCE2: %{?scl_prefix}manpage.sh

%install
install -p -c -m 644 %{SOURCE2} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{?scl:%_root_sysconfdir}%{!?scl:%_sysconfdir}/profile.d/
```

If I'm following this correctly at all, this script isn't a *source* for the package at all but the recommended procedure, from Red Hat, indicates to make it a source.  Why?

Comment: The link you provided was for SCL, which is a whole other beast; a way to run tools, e.g. `python`, that are different versions than the base OS's installed ones. You would need to drop something to configure the `MANPATH` elsewhere. Or ignore your team policy and just [do it the recommended way](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Manpages) with a reasonably named RPM that won't conflict with others.

Comment: @aarondmarasco thank you.  I Thought there might have been something different about the SCL thing.  I didn't recognise it.  I'm basically doing it they recommended way now, except the wildcard to account for changes in compression, so I'll stick with that.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Installing Updated Man pages manually

1. Download man pages from 
   https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/man-pages/man-pages-4.14.tar.gz

2.Extract

tar xvf man-pages-4.14.tar.gz

3.make install

your man pages is update , check using man pthreads ( at bottom it should be written 4.14)